# How to exclude data where the data in two different rows are the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have done research but could not find my answer as I don't know how to word it properly on google, or in the search bar to get the answer I need.

I am working with a data using 3 columns X , Y , Z.
I want to write a query which will tell me:

1. When the data in two different rows in X are the same
2. AND where these two rows have also the same data in Y
3. BUT the data in column Z is different.

I need to have it filtered and I am absolutely confused. 
I tried the `GROUP BY` option but one of the Columns isn't data that can be "grouped by"
I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` and no luck as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select X, Y, count(distinct Z)
from table
group by X, Y
having count(distinct Z) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly, but it appears to work.  Included some sample data to validate results. A more elegant solution exist, but in short order this one works.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X VARCHAR(5),Y VARCHAR(5),Z VARCHAR(5),NOTES VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('A','01','D','DUPE X|'),('B','02','',''),('C','03','',''),('D','04','',''),
('E','05','',''),('F','06','',''),('G','07','',''),('H','08','',''),
('A','09','Z1','DUPE X| DUPE 09| UNIQ Z1' ),('A','09','D','DUPE X| DUPE 09| UNIQ D'),
('A','10','D','DUPE X|'),('A','09','Z2','DUPE X| DUPE 09| UNIQ Z2'),('K','13','',''),
('L','14','',''),('M','15','',''),('A','09','D1','DUPE X| DUPE 09 | DUPE D1'),
('A','09','D1','DUPE X| DUPE 09 | DUPE D1')

SELECT 
    T.X, T.Y , T.Z
FROM
    @T AS T 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT distinct X,Y,COUNT(*) AS XY FROM @T GROUP BY X,Y HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS L ON T.X = L.X AND T.Y = L.Y
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT distinct X,Y,Z,COUNT(*) AS XYZ FROM @T GROUP BY X,Y,Z HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ) AS U ON T.X = U.X AND T.Y = U.Y AND T.Z = U.Z
```